Can the Hamiltonian be defined as energy expressed as a function of position and momentum?
I refined my post in response to having it redirect to another question which addressed the original form of the question.
In Classical mechanics with calculus of variations, and optimal control : an intuitive introduction by Mark Levy, the energy of a conservative one DOF system is given in (1.30) as
$$H\left(x,p\right)=\frac{p^2}{2m}+U\left(x\right).$$
We are then told:

The energy thus expressed in terms of position and momentum is
called the Hamiltonian of the system.

The sentence seems to refer specifically to (1.30).  Nonetheless, it is well-known that the Hamiltonian can be given in more general forms.  So it seems that his assertion could be understood to mean: Any Hamiltonian of the system is equivalent to the energy given as a function of momentum and position.
Is that a correct statement?
I am intentionally being vague regarding the definitions of momentum and position.

It is easy to construct (artificial) examples where the Hamiltonian is not the energy, see e.g. this answer of mine.

Not so artificial actually….
